# Nuxt PWA with directory errors

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, progressive-web-apps, yarnpkg

After a while without playing with Nuxtjs today I decided to start a project on it with PWA support, everything installed and the template created almost as usual, just missing a relatively useless directory - assets -, but when I go to `` `yarn dev` `` several of these errors appear:

```sh
ERROR  ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/runner/anisite/node_modules/.cache/pwa/icon/iphonexsmax_1242x2688.png'
```

then at the end it appears:

```sh
Killed
error Command failed with exit code 137
```

My `package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "anisite",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "lint:js": "eslint --ext \".js,.vue\" --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "lint": "yarn lint:js",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
    "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^3.3.5",
    "core-js": "^3.15.1",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.14.7",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^6.0.1",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^3.0.2",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^4.2.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.2.1",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^27.0.5",
    "eslint": "^7.29.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.12.1",
    "jest": "^27.0.5",
    "postcss": "^8.3.5",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.4"
  }
}
```

###### Edits:

- I already deleted the cache directories
- I already reinstalled everything